# How to interact (tap) a hidden object?

Tags: objective-c, ios

Specifically, I have hidden a uiwebview, but still want to be able to interact with the web view even though it cannot be seen. Is this possible? Or does anyone have an alternate solution?

Comment: make it's alpha 0.1, and set userInteractionEnabled to YES.  Otherwise, there's not much off the top of my head I can remember.

Comment: Couple of questions:
1) Why do you have a web view that you can not see?
2) How will someone know where to tap if they cant see it? Are you trying to have a hidden button? A hidden view accepts no user action.

Comment: @CodaFi Champion! I set alpha to 0.011 and it works like a charm. Not sure why though, but setting alpha to 0.01 removes userinteraction. Ahwell. THe current solution is good enough.

Comment: Glad I could help.  You can (sort of) up vote comments too.

Comment: @CodaFi You should post that comment as an answer so Jesse can accept (and so we can upvote it).

Comment: how do i up vote the comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Chown's suggestion: set the webView's alpha to 0.1 (or lower, but not 0) and userInteractionEnabled to YES.

Answer (score 0):

how about adding a webView programmatically?
once user wants to watch, then add it into a rect of the view.